# Grunt to minify and reference .min files

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I need to:

1. Copy `index.html` to `index.uncompressed.html`
2. Change some the references in `index.html` from `.js` to `.min.js` (i.e. `my_jsfile.js` to `my_jsfile.min.js`)
   3) Minify `index.html`

I am using Grunt.

- Number 3 is no problem.
- I assume number 1 will be easy.
- For number 2, I was planning on using some sort of Grunt editing plugin and changing all `.js` file references between `<!-- Start Here -->` and  `<!-- End here -->` from `my_jsfile.js` to `my_jsfile.min.js`.

Is this the way this type of thing is done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resource I use in this situation is [grunt-processhtml](https://github.com/dciccale/grunt-processhtml), which will do exactly what you're looking for. Check out one of my repos, [steady-backbone-boilerplate](https://github.com/dciccale/grunt-processhtml), where I use this to do exactly what you're describing.

In particular, I find this is a helpful example:

```
<!-- build:[src] js/source.min.js -->
  <script data-main="js/main" src="js/vendor/require.js"></script>
<!-- /build -->
```

So, in development we're using the requirejs script to load all our dependencies. In our production `index.html` file, we're loading the source js file, which has been minified with the `grunt-requirejs` module.